# uninitialized constant ThinkingSphinx::Deltas::DelayedDelta

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I'm attempting to get Thinking Sphinx working w/ Delayed Jobs but I am not having any success. I keep getting the following error:

```
uninitialized constant ThinkingSphinx::Deltas::DelayedDelta
```

I have thinking-sphinx (2.0.2), delayed_job (2.1.3), and ts-delayed-delta (1.1.1) installed. I have restarted sphinx using rake ts:restart. I don't really know what else to try. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hey Kyle, I'm using the exact same stack with no problems whatsoever.
Please, make sure you have something like this in your Gemfile:

```
gem 'ts-delayed-delta', '1.1.1', :require => 'thinking_sphinx/deltas/delayed_delta'
```

If that doesn't help it'd be nice if you provided us with some more context. Backtrace would be nice.

Comment: I was missing ":require => 'thinking_sphinx/deltas/delayed_delta'". Thanks for the help. I'm still new to rails :/